# GNU MathProg: symbolic set vs. integer set

Tags: ampl, glpk, mathprog

My simplified data set in GNU MathProg is as follows, with `Verts` being a set of indices for vertices and `coords` being a table of coordinates of these vertices:

```
data;
set Indices := X Y;
set Verts := 1 2 3 4;

param Coords : X Y :=
1 1.2   0.3
2 4.2   13.0
3 1.5   1.0
4 0.5 0.8;
end;
```

This works, but if I replace the definition of Verts as follows:

```
set Verts := (1..4);
```

the compilation succeeds at this stage but `Verts` now cannot index the parameter table `Coords`. To be specific, `glpsol` returns `Coords[1,X] out of domain`.

Intuitively, I would assume the definition using the shorthand defines an integer set while for indexing I need some sort of symbolic, "string" type.
Is my intuition correct? And if so, how should I write `set Verts := ?;` if I have not 4, but 10 000 elements in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set expressions such as `..` are [not recognized in the AMPL (or MathProg, which is a subset of AMPL) data mode](http://ampl.com/faqs/why-does-set-s-50-70-give-me-a-set-of-only-3-members/). You should list all set members explicitly or move

```
set Verts := 1..4;
```

to the model.